# how to remove timezone ionic and compare the date

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic3

I have a problem with removing the timezone in typescript, I was trying to get the actual date on the day and then convert it to string, but it gives a timezone on the last character.
I want to compare the date from firebase and the date from the actual day in ionic to show the data from firebase. Here is the code

```
myDate = new Date().toISOString().toString();
```

and its the result on the firebase 
**2017-12-16T15:25:51.984Z**

the format date that i want is 2017-12-16

is it possible to compare the string on typescript

Comment: I would suggest moment.js for date/time/datetime manipulation

Comment: how to do that ?

Comment: https://momentjs.com/docs/

Comment: What format you want your date ? put an example so we can help you.

Comment: okay i have add the date that i want to my post, you can see it now

Answer (score 1):

YOu are getting the date format

**myDate = new Date().toISOString().toString();**

and result is  **2017-12-16T15:25:51.984Z**

now we can use,

```
let dateFormat = myDate.split('T');
```

so you will get the two values in array i.e

```
dateFormat = ["2017-12-16", "15:25:51.984Z"]
```

and you can use **dateFormat[0]** for getting date.